# getparameters failed(empty parameters) after starting the recorder

Tags: android, camera, focus

i'm trying to develop a camera app where the user can record a video with tap to focus functionality, i preview the camera, focus in the preview with no problems
but when i start the recorder if i try to get the camera parameters it gives me `getParameters failed (empty parameters)` exception and here is my code

```
public class CustomCameraFragmentFirstPage extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback, View.OnTouchListener, Camera.AutoFocusCallback {

    public CustomCameraFragmentFirstPage() {
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activity = getActivity();
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);

    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_custom_camera_first_page, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
        resetButtons();

        initiateCamera();


        return rootView;
    }

    private void initiateCamera() {
        recording = false;
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        camera = Camera.open();
        initRecorder();
        cameraView = (SurfaceView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.surfaceCamera);

        holder = cameraView.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
//        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        cameraView.setClickable(true);
        cameraView.setOnClickListener(this);
        // rootView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        cameraView.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }


    @SuppressLint({"SdCardPath", "NewApi"})
    private void initRecorder() {

        Random rn = new Random();
        int maximum = 10000000;
        int minimum = 00000001;
        int range = maximum - minimum + 1;
        randomNum = rn.nextInt(range) + minimum + 1 - 10;
//        recorder.setCamera(camera);
//        recorder.setCamera(camera);focus
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);

        recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            recorder.setOrientationHint(90);//plays the video correctly
        } else {
            recorder.setOrientationHint(180);
        }

        mFileName =  /* Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()*/ "/sdcard/";
        mFileName += randomNum + ".ts";
        recorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);

    }

    private void prepareRecorder() {
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
        try {
            //camera.unlock();
            //recorder.setCamera(camera);
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(activity, e.getLocalizedMessage() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(activity, e.getLocalizedMessage() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }


    @OnClick(R.id.save_video)
    public void startEditVideoFragment() {
        startingNewFragment = true;
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.activity_layout_create_video, EditVideoFragment.newInstance(mFileName))
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.pick_gallery_button)
    public void getVideoFromGallery() {

       /* if (sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.SAVE_USER_ID, null) == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ProfileActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("prompt", true);
            startActivity(intent);
            return;
        }*/
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
                &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, Constants.REQUEST_READ_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            openGallery();
        }
    }

    private void openGallery() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"), REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                String selectedVideoPath = MediaSelectorUtils.getVideoFilePathFromUri(getContext(), selectedImageUri);
                if (selectedVideoPath != null) {
                    activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.activity_layout_create_video, EditVideoFragment.newInstance(selectedVideoPath))
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                    /*startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), VideoEditActivity.class)
                            .putExtra(Constants.VIDEO_PATH, selectedVideoPath));*/

                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        ((CreateVideoActivity) activity).toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        startingNewFragment = false;
        initiateCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (!recording && !startingNewFragment) {
            deleteCurrFile();
        } else {
            resetButtons();
            recording = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (!recording && !startingNewFragment) {

            deleteCurrFile();
        } else {
            resetButtons();
            recording = false;
        }
    }

    public void deleteCurrFile() {
        File file = new File(mFileName);
        file.delete();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.back_button)
    public void back() {
        deleteCurrFile();
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), deleted + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        getActivity().onBackPressed();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.cancel_saved_video)
    public void cancel() {
        deleteCurrFile();
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), deleted + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        getActivity().onBackPressed();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.open_flash_button)
    public void flipFlash() {
        flashOn = !flashOn;

        parameters.setFlashMode(flashOn ? Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF : Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.record_button)
    public void record() {
        try {
            if (recording) {
                showAcceptOrRejectButtons();
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.reset();
//                recorder.release();
//                camera.unlock();
            } else {
                if (!checkPermission())
                    requestPermission();
                recordButton.setEnabled(false);
                new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        countdownTimer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        countdownTimer.setText("");
                      //  camera.release();

                        recorder.start();
                        recording = true;
                        hideButtons();
                        recordButton.setEnabled(true);

                    }
                }.start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("EXC", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            Toast.makeText(activity, e.getLocalizedMessage() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    public void initializeCamera() {
        parameters = camera.getParameters();
        camera.cancelAutoFocus();
        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        try {

            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(activity, e.getLocalizedMessage() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        initializeCamera();
        prepareRecorder();
        isCameraCreated = true;

    }


    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                               int height) {
        Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
        if (p.getMaxNumMeteringAreas() > 0) {
            this.meteringAreaSupported = true;
        }

        Log.e("TAG", "surfaceChanged => w=" + width + ", h=" + height);
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        if (holder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            camera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            Camera.Size size = getOptimalSize(parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(), width, height);
            parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
            camera.setParameters(p);
            // camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }


    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        isCameraCreated = false;
        try {
            if (recording) {

                recording = false;
            }
            recorder.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(activity, e.getLocalizedMessage() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        requestPermissions(new
                String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, RECORD_AUDIO, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, RequestPermissionCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RequestPermissionCode:
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    boolean StoragePermission = grantResults[0] ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean RecordPermission = grantResults[1] ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean ReadPermission = grantResults[2] ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if (!(StoragePermission && RecordPermission && ReadPermission)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission Denied " + StoragePermission + "  " + RecordPermission, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                RECORD_AUDIO);

        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    focusOnTouch(motionEvent);
                }
            }, 200);
        //}
        Log.d("TOUCH", "HAPPENED");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean b, Camera camera) {
        //  camera.cancelAutoFocus();
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        if (params.getFocusMode() != Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE) {
            params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            camera.setParameters(params);
        }
    }

    private Rect calculateTapArea(float x, float y, float coefficient) {
        int left = clamp(Float.valueOf((x / cameraView.getWidth()) * 2000 - 1000).intValue(), FOCUS_AREA_SIZE);
        int top = clamp(Float.valueOf((y / cameraView.getHeight()) * 2000 - 1000).intValue(), FOCUS_AREA_SIZE);

        return new Rect(left, top, left + FOCUS_AREA_SIZE, top + FOCUS_AREA_SIZE);
    }

    private int clamp(int touchCoordinateInCameraReper, int focusAreaSize) {
        int result;
        if (Math.abs(touchCoordinateInCameraReper) + focusAreaSize / 2 > 1000) {
            if (touchCoordinateInCameraReper > 0) {
                result = 1000 - focusAreaSize / 2;
            } else {
                result = -1000 + focusAreaSize / 2;
            }
        } else {
            result = touchCoordinateInCameraReper - focusAreaSize / 2;
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected void focusOnTouch(MotionEvent event) {
        if (camera != null) {

            Rect focusRect = calculateTapArea(event.getX(), event.getY(), 1f);
            Rect meteringRect = calculateTapArea(event.getX(), event.getY(), 1.5f);
  //          camera.lock();
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
            if (parameters.getMaxNumFocusAreas() > 0) {
                List<Camera.Area> mylist = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>();
                mylist.add(new Camera.Area(focusRect, 1000));
                parameters.setFocusAreas(mylist);
                if (meteringAreaSupported) {
                    parameters.setMeteringAreas(mylist);
                }
            }
//            camera.unlock();


            camera.setParameters(parameters);



            camera.autoFocus(this);

        }
    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {

        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.2;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null)
            return null;
        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        int targetHeight = h;
        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
//          Log.d("CameraActivity", "Checking size " + size.width + "w " + size.height + "h");
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }


//      Log.d("CameraActivity", "Using size: " + optimalSize.width + "w " + optimalSize.height + "h");
        return optimalSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure to keep your questions minimal. Nobody likes to go through that much code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: When the camera is recording, it's not *yours* anymore. Furthermore, `setParameters()` is not guaranteed to work when camera preview is started. Note that you use an old, deprecated Camera API. If your device is API 21 or better, consider switching to the new [**android.hardware.camera2**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) API, which lifts many limitations. Still you may need to implement recording not though **MediaRecorder**, if you need better control of the session.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i initialized the recorder before the surface is created, so all i did is i removed the `initRecorder()` function call from  initializing the camera and called it form `onSurfaceCreated()`